# Mustache/Hogan JS: Is it possible to reference parent tags within a list?

Tags: templating, mustache, hogan.js

I have a use case where I'd like to access parent tags within list loop sections in a Mustache/Hogan JS template.

For example, this is my data structure:

```
var data = {
  users: [{name: "John", age: 100},{name: "Max", age: 80}],
  meta: {membership: "full"}
};
```

..and this is my Mustache/Hogan JS template:

```
{{#users}}
h1 Hello there, {{name}}
{{/users}}
```

..which renders as:

```
<h1>Hello there, John</h1>
<h1>Hello there, Max</h1>
```

This is all well and good, but is it possible for me to access the **meta.membership** parent variable within the **{{#users}...{{/users}}** section? It seems that the tags are limited to the local context, so I can't output the value of the meta.membership tag while iterating over users.

Ideally I want to know if something like this is possible:

```
{{#users}}
h1 Hello there, {{name}}
p You have a {{meta.membership}} membership
{{/users}}
```

Desired result:

```
<h1>Hello there, John</h1>
<p>You have a full membership</p>
<h1>Hello there, Max</h1>
<p>You have a full membership</p>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error)!

It turns out Hogan JS does support the [Context Bubbling spec](https://github.com/mustache/spec/blob/master/specs/sections.yml) so my desired input as per the question does in fact evaluate to my desired output! :) I was just having problems getting this to work as expected because I was dealing with a heavily nested dataset & several Mustache includes so I had made a few silly errors along the way that were giving me blank outputs.

All good now - though I think I'd better go find me a Hogan debugger to save from further frustration in the future... ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
{{#users}}
h1 Hello there, {{name}}
p You have a {{#meta.membership}} membership
{{/users}}
```

**OR**

```
{{#users #meta}}
h1 Hello there, {{name}}
p You have a {{membership}} membership
{{/users}}
```

Try it... Could work since the structure of the data-array would allow it to work

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, unfortunately neither of these work. :( I'm thinking I may just need to change my data structure to accomodate the limitation in context.